# Question about javascript alert asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, javascript, alert

I'm working on a web page that saves in user information on a button click and then redirects the page.

However, I want to alert the user if he/she forgets to fill in a value in one of the controls.
and ask to correct the error and click the save button again..

I implemented a similar function with confirmbox but since the alert box does not have a return value I was wondering if such an implementation is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server Side**

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return myFunction();" OnClick="MyButton_Click" Text="Save" />
```

**Client Side**

```
function myFunction() {
     if (document.getElementById("<%=this.MyFieldName.ClientID%>").value.length == 0) {
         alert('Please fill in the field.');
         return false;
     }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. but for some reason the code is not working on my web page. Where should the javascript code be placed? in the master page or the page with the button

Comment: Place it in the page that has the button.

Comment: Thanks again... for some reason the doc.getbyid wasnt working on the elements real name, it had to be changed to its runtime name by appending ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a asp:RequiredFieldValidator tag and let the ASP.Net validation logic do all the checking and user prompting for you.

Comment: True, but you get total control on what and how things happen if you set up your own function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going to validate with custom JavaScript and alert boxes, try to reuse the standard ASP.net validation controls. There are a bunch of them available for required fields, comparison validators, custom validators etc. The advantage is that you use standard mechanisms and that you can access them for doing server-side as well as client-side validation. The server-side validation is important if your user has JavaScript disabled in his browser which still seems to happen.

Moreover I actually prefer that things happen directly on the page and not with alert boxes (this is somehow the old way of doing things). Alert boxes lower the user experience since he continuously has to click it away and moreover he has to read what happened, while if the error is shown directly beneath its source makes it easier to see (just from a usability point of view).

You could alternatively also look at the jQuery validation mechanism. As far as I know there exists one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a return value.  Your function can cancel the button submission by just returning false.

```
function myBtnClick()
{
   if (document.getElementById("myTextBox").value == "")
   {   
      alert("You forgot to fill it in!");
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could change the text in your alert box to a question and use a confirm box instead:

```
if (document.getElementById('myTextBox').value == "")
{
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to exit without filling in ... ?');
}
```